# What is the better way of authentication for REST API in Azure

Tags: rest, azure

Wanted to make rest calls, i found there are two ways of authentication.

Method 1. Upload a self-signed ssl certificate and authenticate through certificate and subscription id.

Method 2. Use access token (Bearer ey...) which is obtained from making oauth2 call.

Which method is best way to do?

Answer (score 1):

You should go with Method 2 for many reasons:

- Method 1 is the old way and will only work with authenticating Service Management API requests where as Method 2 is the new way and will work with authenticating both Service Management API and Azure Resource Manager API requests.
- Azure is moving away from Service Management API and is moving towards Resource Manager API which only supports Method 2. In fact, wherever possible use Resource Manager API instead of Service Management API. Only use Service Management API when there's no Resource Manager API equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the reply